# Apache Airflow UI shows DAG import error (IndexError: list index out of range) But DAG works fine

Tags: python, bash, airflow

This is my scriptlet for triggerring the python script.

```
task1= BashOperator(
    task_id='task1_monthly_run',
    bash_command="python /opt/airflow/dags/scripts/validation/runner.py arg1 arg2",
    dag=dag)
```

I give 2 args for using in py script. Because I use same script for different args.

this is from runner.py to show the usage of args:

```
import sys
arg_list = sys.argv[1:]
model_name = arg_list[0]
val_date_son = arg_list[1]
```

Code works fine. args pass fine. But Airflow UI shows error about args:

> Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/scripts/validation/runner.py] Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File "", line
> 219, in _call_with_frames_removed   File
> "/opt/airflow/dags/scripts/validation/runner.py", line 10, in 
> val_date_son = arg_list[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc3Sk.png) IndexError: list index out of range

[DAG import errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc3Sk.png)

How can i get rid of this error?

Comment: Which is the length of your `arg_list` variable?

Comment: What is runner.py ? is that a file that contains DAGs or just a lib helper?

Comment: @ÁlvaroCuarteroMontilla length of arg_list depends on bash command. bash_command="python /opt/airflow/dags/scripts/validation/runner.py arg1 arg2" here is length 3. 1-runner.py, 2-arg1, 3-arg2

Comment: @EladKalif runner.py is my main script. DAG script triggers it via bash command. you can see above

Comment: By the way, my code and DAG work perfectly. But Airflow UI just shows this error. Why it detects code like an error even if i dont run the DAG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow discover DAGs by looking over all `.py` files in the DAG directory.
Furthermore, Airflow has optimization to consider only `.py` that contains the words `dag` and `airflow` ([dag_discovery_safe_mode](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-discovery-safe-mode)). In your case `runner.py` probably contains the strings `dag` and `airflow` as a result Airflow try to parse the file and look for DAGs but since this is a script Airflow encounter an error and raises Broken DAG message.

The reason you are able to execute the DAG successfully though there is a Broken DAG message is because the message is not on the DAG - it's on the `runner.py`. Executing it as you meant (via BashOperator) works fine but trying to parse the script as DAG file results in error.

To solve your issue you need to set [`.airflowignore`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#airflowignore) this will tell Airflow not to parse `.py` files under `/dags/scripts/` as under scripts folder you should not store dag files.

Alternatively you can replace occurrences of `dag` and `airflow` strings in `runner.py` - it will not show the Broken DAG message but Airflow will still try to parse the file so the `.airflowignore` solution is prefered.

Comment: This solution works like a charm. I'm new to Airflow. I haven't even known there is an ignore configuration like git. Thank you very much!! This information also covers my future UI errors :)